# using tryCatch with Sys.sleep upon encountering an error

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `tryCatch` and `Sys.sleep` to automate the following chunk so I don't need to keep coming back and re-running the code every 15 minutes.

Twitter allows for a certain number of tweets to be downloaded every 15 minutes. After you've reached the maximum there's an error message. After 15 minutes upon receiving the error message the number of tweets you can download resets.

The list (x) is of a few hundred handles that I need to download tweets for.

```
# get initial list of Twitter Handles from df
x <- as.vector(df$Handle)

# get list of existing files from folder
f <- list.files("C:/workDump/")

# subset list of files if necessary
xSubset <- x[length(f):(length(x))]

# download the twitter timeline data for list elements which do not exist
for (i in xSubset){
  timeline <- userTimeline(i,n = 3200)
  timeline <- twListToDF(timeline)
  save(timeline, file=paste("workDump/", i, ".Rda"))
}
```

I've played with many various specifications of `tryCatch` and `Sys.sleep` that at this point I'm just confusing myself.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot use your code, I can only guess:

```
R.utils::evalWithTimeout({
    repeat {
      res <- try(
        # Your code
      })
      # Handle error from try if necessary:
      if (class(res) != "try-error") {
        # Your code
      }
    }
  }, timeout = 15*60, onTimeout = "warning")
```

with a timeout of 15*60 seconds.