# delay a function if it throws an error: try_catch and if else

Tags: r, try-catch, delay

I try to write a `function` that will be repeated with a certain delay (only once in my example, better would be twice with different time delay) if it throws an error. If the function does not work after 2 attempts, it should return `NA`.
`read.csv` is just an example for illustration, in my real data it is a scraping function.

this post was somewhat helpful [using tryCatch with Sys.sleep upon encountering an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341603/using-trycatch-with-sys-sleep-upon-encountering-an-error) . However, I did not figure out how to implement multiple attempts.

**My Approach:**

```
muhur <- function(x){if (is.na(try_catch({read.csv(x)},
                                         .w=function(w){message("error1")},
                                         .e=function(e){return(NA_character_)})))
{message("warning, delay 10 s")
  Sys.sleep(10)
  try_catch({read.csv(x)},
            .w=function(w){message("error2")},
            .e=function(e){return(NA_character_)})}
  else {try_catch({read.csv(x)},
                  .w=function(w)message("error3"),
                  .e=function(e)return(NA_character_))}
  }
```

**My Problem:**

My Approach is a quite laborious and does not throw the first error message. Moreover, I do not know how to implement a second attempt.

```
test<- data.frame(a=c("test1","test"))
test%>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(b=muhur(a))

warning, delay 10 s
warning, delay 10 s
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   a [2]
  a     b    
  <fct> <chr>
1 test1 <NA> 
2 test  <NA>
```

**My Question:**

Is there any better (saver, clearer) approach to my problem?

Comment: I would use recursion.

Comment: Have you tried `withRestarts`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38658625/2554330.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on Roland's suggestion:

```
muhur <- function(x, tries = 2){
  if (tries <= 0)
    stop("Too many tries")
  result <- try(read.csv(x))
  if (inherits(result, "try-error")) {
    cat("Failed, trying again in 10 seconds...\n")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    muhur(x, tries = tries - 1)
  } else
    result
}
```

I couldn't get a `withRestarts` solution to work; I find its documentation and blog writeups about it all pretty opaque.

Comment: Thanks. Looks great. how can I stop the tries and return NA?